# Executing a stored procedure through SQL*Plus

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, sqlplus

I created a procedure:

```
PROCEDURE PROCEDURE1(
            p_str IN varchar2,
            cursor_fetch out REF_CURSOR,
            p_str2 OUT VARCHAR2,
            p_success OUT VARCHAR2 
            ) 
-- Proc Body --
End PROCEDURE1;
```

Now while executing the procedure through SQL*Plus

```
SQL>var cur refcursor;
SQL>var a varchar2;
SQL>var b varchar2;
SQL>exec PROCEDURE1('Hi',:cur,:a,:b);
```

it displays an error:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at "PROCEDURE1", line 58
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any exception block, then this will reveal the reason behind the error, since the line number would be correct :

`ORA-06512: at "PROCEDURE1", line 58`

Since we don't have your code, we don't know what's going on at line 58. But, you have the error stack to debug.